# how to show the data of CPT UI plugin on website?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have used CPT UI to add some posts with taxonomies. I have filled two post data in CPT UI for practice. Now I want to show these post on a page. What all code I have to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Wp_Query along with the post name that you created using CPT Ui plugin to display those posts. Like, e.g. i had created a post named as school then code to display all posts of School type is as following :

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'school' ) );
while($query->have_posts()):
    $query->the_post();
    echo $query->ID; // it will print the ID of post
endwhile;
```

Hope this will clear the things..

Answer (score 0):

In order to pull in the custom fields/post meta, you will need to write some code within the WordPress loop (https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) in your template file.

> The Loop is PHP code used by WordPress to display posts. Using The Loop, WordPress processes each post to be displayed on the current page, and formats it according to how it matches specified criteria within The Loop tags. Any HTML or PHP code in the Loop will be processed on each post.

eg.

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
```

For all post meta:

`$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $meta );
    echo '</pre>';`

Or for a single value:

`$custom_field_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_field_key_name', true );`

See below for more information in the WordPress Codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

and

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: What do you mean by "within the WP loop in your template file:"